# Entity framework Data saving issue

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-4

I am running into very strange issue with entity framework.
I am saving data to the database using entity framework. When I call SaveChanges() method, then data is saving to the database, I can even see my updates in database in SQL.
But when I close my application and reopen data will be loss in the database and it is showing previous data which was before my first save. 
This is happening even when I select different record in the application and save, then the previous record data will be loss. 
I have tried all possible options, nothing helped me.

**Below is the code snippet.**

```cs
AxRetailPosDb context = new AxRetailPosDb(DbContextHelper.DbContextConnectionString(this.Application.Settings.Database.Connection.ConnectionString));
bool flag = false;
try
{
  CUSTTABLE cust = context.CUSTTABLEs.Where(c => c.ACCOUNTNUM == customer.CustomerId).FirstOrDefault();
  DIRPARTYTABLE dirpartytbl = context.DIRPARTYTABLEs.Where(p => p.RECID == cust.PARTY).FirstOrDefault();
  if (cust != null)
  {
    cust.IGNDELIVERYCODE = cusEextView.DeliveryCode;
    if (cusEextView.Birthday != null && cusEextView.Birthday != Convert.ToDateTime("01-01-0001"))
    {
      cust.IGNBIRTHDATE = Convert.ToDateTime(cusEextView.Birthday.ToShortDateString());
    }
    cust.IGNMODELSCORE = cusEextView.Modelscore;
    cust.CREDITMAX = cusEextView.ChargeLimit;
    if (cusEextView.Gender != null)
    {
      cust.IGNGENDER = (int)Enum.Parse(typeof(Microsoft.Dynamics.Retail.Pos.Customer.WinFormsTouch.frmNewCustomer.Gender), cusEextView.Gender);
    }
  }
  if (dirpartytbl != null)
  {
    dirpartytbl.LANGUAGEID = customer.Language;
  }

  context.SaveChanges();
}
catch
{
}
finally
{
  if (context != null)
  {
    context.Dispose();
  }
}
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you use using for context variable, which will take care of disposing ? like here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

Comment: Is this code called before app close?

Comment: This code did not call before app close.

Comment: So any changes you have aren't save before app close.

Comment: Initially i have used using statement and it did not work. An then after i tried without using statement.

Comment: The using couldn't have been the cause that makes you lose data.

Comment: Are you using `TransactionScope`?

Comment: The empty catch block is probably catching an exception and you don't realize an exception is being thrown.

Comment: What is the database? Its not a SqlExpress which gets overwritten after every build is it?